# Power shell script with GUI performs slowly

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface

I have created a gui with powershell that allows me to copy files from inside folders into one place .

Example you have a folder A and in folder A there is Folder B and C inside all these folders you have a bunch of logfiles named logfile + date.log

My app can hunt through all the folders and move copy the log files to a single location.

The script works but when it is getting a list of files to copy it is slow and says "Not responding" at the top of the window next to where it says "Copy Files To One Directory"

I have added the script can you guys have a look and let me know how to speed it up.
The functions it hik are causing the problem are after the "These are the function I seems to be having a problem with"

Thank for the help.
The code

```
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Source File Information (DO NOT MODIFY)
    # Source ID: 3020bcd1-4cba-4aca-968e-b4bc4ca05d76
    # Source File: Copy\Copy.pfproj
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #========================================================================
    # Generated On: 11/15/2011 5:11 PM
    # Generated By: justin
    #========================================================================
```

`#----------------------------------------------
#region Import Assemblies
#----------------------------------------------
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load("mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
#endregion Import Assemblies

#Define a Param block to use custom parameters in the project
#Param ($CustomParameter)

function Main {
    Param ([String]$Commandline)
    #Note: This function starts the application
    #Note: $Commandline contains the complete argument string passed to the packager
    #Note: $Args contains the parsed arguments passed to the packager (Type: System.Array) 
    #Note: To get the script directory in the Packager use: Split-Path $hostinvocation.MyCommand.path
    #Note: To get the console output in the Packager (Windows Mode) use: $ConsoleOutput (Type: System.Collections.ArrayList)
    #TODO: Initialize and add Function calls to forms

    if((Call-MainForm_pff) -eq "OK")
    {

    }

    $global:ExitCode = 0 #Set the exit code for the Packager
}








#region Call-MainForm_pff
function Call-MainForm_pff
{
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Import the Assemblies
    #----------------------------------------------
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load("mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
    #endregion Import Assemblies

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Objects
    #----------------------------------------------
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $labelExtension = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $labelFileName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Extension = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $FileName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $buttonSetDestination = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $buttonSetSource = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Dlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Slabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $DestinationFolder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $SourceFolder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $progress = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $buttonCopyFiles = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $sourcebrowserdialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $destinationbrowserdialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    # User Generated Script
    #----------------------------------------------

    $OnLoadFormEvent={


    }



    $buttonSetSource_Click={

        $result = $sourcebrowserdialog.ShowDialog()  
         if ($result -eq 'Ok'){    
          $SourceFolder.Text =$sourcebrowserdialog.SelectedPath 
         }
         else{
          $SourceFolder.Text = ''  
         }  
    }

    $buttonSetDestination_Click={

        $result = $destinationbrowserdialog.ShowDialog()  
         if ($result -eq 'Ok'){    
          $DestinationFolder.Text =$destinationbrowserdialog.SelectedPath 
         }
         else{
          $DestinationFolder.Text = ''  
         }  
    }

    $buttonCopyFiles_Click={
        #TODO: Place custom script here

        $progress.Value = 0

        $CName = $FileName.Text
        $CExtension = "." + $Extension.Text
        $CSource = $SourceFolder.Text 
        $CDestination = $DestinationFolder.Text

        CopyfFiles $CSource $CDestination $CName $CExtension
    }
        # --End User Generated Script--
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Events
    #----------------------------------------------

    $Form_StateCorrection_Load=
    {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    $Form_StoreValues_Closing=
    {
        #Store the control values
        $script:MainForm_Extension = $Extension.Text
        $script:MainForm_FileName = $FileName.Text
        $script:MainForm_DestinationFolder = $DestinationFolder.Text
        $script:MainForm_SourceFolder = $SourceFolder.Text
    }


    $Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
    {
        #Remove all event handlers from the controls
        try
        {
            $buttonSetDestination.remove_Click($buttonSetDestination_Click)
            $buttonSetSource.remove_Click($buttonSetSource_Click)
            $buttonCopyFiles.remove_Click($buttonCopyFiles_Click)
            $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.remove_Load($OnLoadFormEvent)
            $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
            $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.remove_Closing($Form_StoreValues_Closing)
            $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
        }
        catch [Exception]
        { }
    }
    #endregion Generated Events

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    #----------------------------------------------
    #
    # CopyFilesToOneDirectoy
    #
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($labelExtension)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($labelFileName)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($Extension)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($FileName)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($buttonSetDestination)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($buttonSetSource)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($Dlabel)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($Slabel)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($DestinationFolder)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($SourceFolder)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($progress)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Controls.Add($buttonCopyFiles)
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.ClientSize = '458, 245'
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Name = "CopyFilesToOneDirectoy"
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.Text = "Copy Files To One Directoy"
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.add_Load($OnLoadFormEvent)
    #
    # labelExtension
    #
    $labelExtension.AutoSize = $True
    $labelExtension.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt, style=Bold"
    $labelExtension.Location = '349, 54'
    $labelExtension.Name = "labelExtension"
    $labelExtension.Size = '75, 16'
    $labelExtension.TabIndex = 11
    $labelExtension.Text = "Extension"
    #
    # labelFileName
    #
    $labelFileName.AutoSize = $True
    $labelFileName.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt, style=Bold"
    $labelFileName.Location = '12, 54'
    $labelFileName.Name = "labelFileName"
    $labelFileName.Size = '79, 16'
    $labelFileName.TabIndex = 10
    $labelFileName.Text = "File Name"
    #
    # Extension
    #
    $Extension.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt"
    $Extension.Location = '349, 74'
    $Extension.Name = "Extension"
    $Extension.Size = '93, 22'
    $Extension.TabIndex = 9
    #
    # FileName
    #
    $FileName.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt"
    $FileName.Location = '12, 74'
    $FileName.Name = "FileName"
    $FileName.Size = '300, 22'
    $FileName.TabIndex = 8
    #
    # buttonSetDestination
    #
    $buttonSetDestination.Location = '349, 173'
    $buttonSetDestination.Name = "buttonSetDestination"
    $buttonSetDestination.Size = '93, 23'
    $buttonSetDestination.TabIndex = 7
    $buttonSetDestination.Text = "Set Destination"
    $buttonSetDestination.TextAlign = 'MiddleLeft'
    $buttonSetDestination.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonSetDestination.add_Click($buttonSetDestination_Click)
    #
    # buttonSetSource
    #
    $buttonSetSource.Location = '349, 123'
    $buttonSetSource.Name = "buttonSetSource"
    $buttonSetSource.Size = '93, 23'
    $buttonSetSource.TabIndex = 6
    $buttonSetSource.Text = "Set Source"
    $buttonSetSource.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonSetSource.add_Click($buttonSetSource_Click)
    #
    # Dlabel
    #
    $Dlabel.AutoSize = $True
    $Dlabel.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt, style=Bold"
    $Dlabel.Location = '12, 154'
    $Dlabel.Name = "Dlabel"
    $Dlabel.Size = '135, 16'
    $Dlabel.TabIndex = 5
    $Dlabel.Text = "Destination Folder"
    #
    # Slabel
    #
    $Slabel.AutoSize = $True
    $Slabel.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt, style=Bold"
    $Slabel.Location = '12, 104'
    $Slabel.Name = "Slabel"
    $Slabel.Size = '106, 16'
    $Slabel.TabIndex = 4
    $Slabel.Text = "Source Folder"
    #
    # DestinationFolder
    #
    $DestinationFolder.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt"
    $DestinationFolder.Location = '12, 174'
    $DestinationFolder.Name = "DestinationFolder"
    $DestinationFolder.Size = '300, 22'
    $DestinationFolder.TabIndex = 3
    $DestinationFolder.Text = "c:\td"
    #
    # SourceFolder
    #
    $SourceFolder.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt"
    $SourceFolder.Location = '12, 124'
    $SourceFolder.Name = "SourceFolder"
    $SourceFolder.Size = '300, 22'
    $SourceFolder.TabIndex = 2
    $SourceFolder.Text = "c:\ts"
    #
    # progress
    #
    $progress.Location = '12, 212'
    $progress.Name = "progress"
    $progress.Size = '300, 23'
    $progress.TabIndex = 1
    #
    # buttonCopyFiles
    #
    $buttonCopyFiles.Location = '349, 212'
    $buttonCopyFiles.Name = "buttonCopyFiles"
    $buttonCopyFiles.Size = '93, 23'
    $buttonCopyFiles.TabIndex = 0
    $buttonCopyFiles.Text = "Copy Files"
    $buttonCopyFiles.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonCopyFiles.add_Click($buttonCopyFiles_Click)
    #
    # sourcebrowserdialog
    #
    $sourcebrowserdialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer'
    $sourcebrowserdialog.ShowNewFolderButton = $False
    #
    # destinationbrowserdialog
    #
    $destinationbrowserdialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer'
    $destinationbrowserdialog.ShowNewFolderButton = $False
    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #----------------------------------------------

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
    #Clean up the control events
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    #Store the control values when form is closing
    $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.add_Closing($Form_StoreValues_Closing)
    #Show the Form
    return $CopyFilesToOneDirectoy.ShowDialog()

}
#endregion

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These are the function I seems to be havig a problem with     

    #Sample function that provides the location of the script
    function Get-ScriptDirectory
    { 
        if($hostinvocation -ne $null)
        {
            Split-Path $hostinvocation.MyCommand.path
        }
        else
        {
            Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
        }
    }

    function ListOfFiles ($Source,$Name,$Extension){

    $FileListArray = @()

    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $Source -Force -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -like $Name -and $_.Extension -eq $Extension})
    { 
      If ($FileListArray -match "$file")
            {       
            $NewFileName = $file.Directory.Name + "." + $file.Name
            $FileListArray += ,@($file,$file.FullName,$NewFileName)
            }
        Else
            {
            $FileListArray += ,@($file,$file.FullName,$file)    
            }

    }
    Return $FileListArray
    }



    Function CopyfFiles ($Source,$Destination,$Name,$Extension){

        $ListFiles  = @(listOfFiles -Source $Source -Name $Name -Extension $Extension)
        $ListFilesTemp = @()

        Foreach ($CF in $ListFiles)
        { 
            $Check = $Destination + "\"+ $CF[2]
                #If The File is Not Already In The Destination Add It To The Temp Array 
                IF (Test-Path -Path "$Check")
                    {}
                Else
                    {$ListFilesTemp += ,@($CF[0],$CF[1],$CF[2])}

            $ListFiles = $ListFilesTemp
        }

        $progress.Minimum = 0
        $progress.Maximum = $ListFiles.Count  
        $progress.Step = 1


        Foreach ($File in $ListFiles)

        { 
        $FileDestination = $Destination + "\"+ $File[2]
        Copy-Item -Path $File[1] -Destination $FileDestination
        $progress.PerformStep()
        }

    }

    #Sample variable that provides the location of the script
    [string]$ScriptDirectory = Get-ScriptDirectory

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

#endregion

#Start the application
Main ($CommandLine)
<code>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not Responding" means the thread isn't waiting for windowing input (in your example the thread is running the powershell code). I don't think there is a trivial way to create new threads in Powershell. However, you might be able to make your GUI more responsive using **PowerBoots** and **powershell jobs** like in this [example](http://poshcode.org/2315).

Comment: Ok thanks will look in to it , I just copyed the file to my windows home server and ran it and now when i click the set source button the thing hangs and says Not Responding when in actual fact a dialog box is meant to pop up and let me select a source , have no idea why . Really confused how it can work when I run it through primal forms  but if i export it and try run it i have all these strange problems .Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring local variables inside a function (Call-MainForm_pff) and using these variables in other function. That will not work. See sample code. Only $Var2 will be displayed.

```
#=================
Function One-Set-Value {
    $Var1 = "This is a test."
}

Function Two-Display-Value
{
    $Var2 = "This is a second test."
    Write-Host "Var2" $Var2
    Write-Host "Var1" $Var1
}
One-Set-Value
Two-Display-Value
#=================
```

Convert these variables in to functions. This will work with return values.